# rvalue refs and std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Can someone explain why B doesn't compile, but C does?  I don't understand why std::move is required since the variable is already an rvalue ref.

```
struct A {
  int x;
  A(int x=0) : x(x) {}
  A(A&& a) : x(a.x) { a.x = 0; }
};

struct B : public A {
  B() {}
  B(B&& b) : A(b) {}  // compile error with g++-4.7
};

struct C : public A {
  C() {}
  C(C&& c) : A(std::move(c)) {}  // ok, but why?
};
```

Answer (score 25):

In the statement:

```
B(B&& b)
```

The **parameter** `b` is declared with the type:  rvalue reference to `B`.

In the statement:

```
A(b)
```

The **expression** `b` is an lvalue of type `B`.

And lvalue expressions can not bind to rvalue references:  specifically the rvalue reference in the statement:

```
A(A&& a)
```

This logic follows cleanly from other parts of the language.  Consider this function:

```
void
f(B& b1, B b2, B&& b3)
{
   g(b1);
   g(b2);
   g(b3);
}
```

Even though the parameters of `f` are all declared with different types, the expressions `b1`, `b2` and `b3` are all lvalue expressions of type `B`, and thus would all call the same function `g`, no matter how `g` is overloaded.

In C++11 it is more important than ever to distinguish between a variable's declaration, and the expression that results from using that variable.  And expressions never have reference type.  Instead they have a *value category* of precisely one of: lvalue, xvalue, prvalue.

The statement:

```
A(std::move(c))
```

is ok, because `std::move` returns an rvalue reference.  The expression resulting from a function call returning an rvalue reference has value category: xvalue.  And together with prvalues, xvalues are considered rvalues.  And the rvalue expression of type `C`:

```
std::move(c)
```

will bind to the rvalue reference parameter in: `A(A&& a)`.

I find the following diagram (originally invented by Bjarne Stroustrup) very helpful:

```
       expression
          /  \
    glvalue  rvalue
     /  \    /  \
lvalue  xvalue  prvalue
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer.  Clearly there's a lot of subtlety here to be understood.

Answer (score 14):

Because named variables are not rvalues, even when declared &&. If it has a name then its not temporary, thus you need to use `std::move`.