# std::enable_if with std::is_reference fails to compile 

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, enable-if

Like `std::reference_wrapper` uses a pointer under the covers to store a "reference", I am trying to do something similar with the following code.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
    void* _ptr;

    template<typename T>
    Foo(T val,
        typename std::enable_if
            <
                std::is_reference<T>::value,
                void
            >::type* = nullptr)
        : _ptr(&val)
    { }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int& l = i;

    Foo u2(l);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this fails to compile:

```
CXX main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(int&)’
main.cpp:23:13: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:8:5: note: template<class T> Foo::Foo(T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<_Tp>::value, void>::type*)
main.cpp:8:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> Foo::Foo(T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<_Tp>::value, void>::type*) [with T = int]’:
main.cpp:23:13:   required from here
main.cpp:8:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
main.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
main.cpp:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Foo&’
main.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr Foo::Foo(Foo&&)
main.cpp:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Foo&&’
```

How can I make the `enable_if` return true for reference parameters?

Comment: The obvious answer is to conditionate on _is_reference && !is_integral_ and the opposite of that, it works but is not a good answer...

Comment: @K-ballo I have simplified my problem, and will edit the question to more accurately reflect the problem - which is how to get `enable_if<is_reference> to be valid for references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T` in this case will never be deduced to be a reference type.  In your construction of the object `u2`, the constructor template argument is deduced to be `int`.

While the type of the variable `u2` is `int&`, when you *use* `u2` in an expression, it is an lvalue expression of type `int`.  [An expression never has reference type.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238252/151292)

Template argument deduction uses the types of the function arguments to deduce the template parameter types.  Function arguments are expressions.  Therefore, because no expression has reference type, a template argument will never be deduced to be a reference type.

[In C++11, if a function argument has type `T&&`, `T` may be deduced to the type `T&` if the argument is an lvalue.  This mechanism enables perfect forwarding.  That's not related to your scenario, though.]

In effect, in an expression, an object and a reference to that object are indistinguishable.  A reference just allows you to give another name to the object.

Comment: James, this is part of a more complex piece of code where I'm trying to use `enable_if` to differentiate between integers, pointers and l-value references. As such, is what I'm trying to do even possible using `enable_if`?

Comment: No, because [expressions never have reference type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10238252/151292).  Why do you think you need to distinguish between "a reference to an object" and "an object"?

Comment: I am trying to use a union to store different data types - if it is of integral-type I store the value itself in the `union::uint64_t` member, if it is a pointer I store the value itself in the `union::void*` member, if it is a reference, I store the **address** of the reference in the `union::void*` member. I want to overload the union constructor to use template argument deduction to know how to handle the input argument

Comment: I do not understand why you want to treat `i` and `l` differently.  `l` is just another name for `i`.  When you use the two in an expression, they are indistinguishable.

Comment: I have a union which is copied between threads. To prevent excessive copying I want to restrict the values which can be stored in the union to be either integral (up to a maximum of 64 bits), pointers or references. I have a static_assert on the size of the argument being a maximum of 64 bits. Currently I can store a pointer to a large object, but not a reference (for the very reason you state, the argument is deduced to be `T`, not `T&`). I want to be able to deduce a `T&` parameter, and store `union.ptr = &obj`

Comment: In this case, explicit would be much better than implicit, I think, and you should either require a pointer or use `std::ref` or a similar technique.